# How is the recursion in the following question works?

Tags: arrays, c, xcode, recursion, numbers

I have a question and a solution from a test.

The question is: write a function that returns 1 if we can split an array to 2 different groups that their sum is equal, otherwise return 0.
For example: the array: [1,4,0,3] can be divided into 2 groups that their sum is equal, hence: 1+3=0+4

The solution suggested is written below:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int can_split(int arr[], int n, int sum1, int sum2); // Function Signature

int can_split(int arr[], int n, int sum1, int sum2)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return sum1 == sum2;
    return can_split(arr + 1, n - 1, sum1 + arr[0], sum2) || can_split(arr + 1, n - 1, sum1, sum2 + arr[0]);
}

int main()
{
    int sum1_main = 0, sum2_main = 0;
    int arr_main[] = { 1,2,4 };
    printf("Function returned: %d", can_split(arr_main, 4, sum1_main, sum2_main));
    return 0;
}
```

What I did not understand is the idea of the line:

```
return can_split(arr + 1, n - 1, sum1 + arr[0], sum2) || can_split(arr + 1, n - 1, sum1, sum2 + arr[0]);
```

Recursion is very hard topic for me when it comes to complicated questions.

It will be much obliged if someone can explain how this line works and why did the teacher wrote || ?
I know it means "OR", but what does it do here exactly?

Comment: When the first part is true, it returns true and the second part is not performed. Otherwise it returns the return value of the second part.

Comment: At the first level of the recursion, the algorithm is dispatching the first element of the array to first or the second subset with respective sum sum1 and sum2: the left and the right side of the ||.
At the second level of the recursion, it is doing the same with second element of the array and so on. 
It finally iterate through a binary tree dispatching elements in either subset1 or subset2 ending the search when it finds a leaf where sum1 = sum2

Comment: Shouldn't `can_split(arr_main, 4, sum1_main, sum2_main))` in `main` be `can_split(arr_main, 3, sum1_main, sum2_main))` with the array of `int arr_main[] = { 1,2,4 };` as the parameter `n` is the amount of elements? --- Better to use `can_split(arr_main, sizeof(arr_main) / sizeof(*arr_main), sum1_main, sum2_main))`.

Answer (score 0):

> Recursion is very hard topic for me when it comes to complicated
> questions.

Recursion is not so much a hard topic, but rather a way to think and see code (and more than just code). It is mainly a question of habit and practice, the more you will read, write and think recursive, the more it should look natural to you.
I'll add that imho, it is an unavoidable and necessary concept to master when it comes to software development or computer science.

About this line:

```
return can_split(arr + 1, n - 1, sum1 + arr[0], sum2) || can_split(arr + 1, n - 1, sum1, sum2 + arr[0]);
```

The meaning of the variables is the following:

- `arr` represents the address of the current element of the array that we are considering. At each step of the recursive calls, we will consider the next element (hence the `arr + 1` which points to the next element in the array)
- `n` represents the number of elements left to consider: we start the very first call to the function with `n = 4` which represents the length of the array. We use `n` as a stopping condition. When `n == 0`, we know that all elements have been considered.
- `sum1` and `sum2` represent the current summed values

Now, the meaning of line is the following:
"This array can be split in two groups of equal sum if and only if
-> the array can be split in two groups of equal sum with the current element in the first group
OR (hence the `||`)
-> the array can be split in two groups of equal sum with the current element in the second group ."

We do that for each element, which guarantees that we will get the correct result ultimately.

As often, a good way to understand code is to run it by hand on a small example (here arr_main will be `{1, 3, 0, 4}`).
Here is how it starts:

```
can_split(arr_main, 4, 0, 0)  // no element has been affected to any sum
n == 0 ? no so we continue
return can_split(arr + 1, 3, 1, 0)   // the value 1 is affected to sum1
             || 
       can_split(arr + 1, 3, 0, 1);  // the value 1 is affected to sum2
```

and on and on, until all values have been affected.